# "Reorganize or delete items in your Links list" appearing in top bar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, top-link-bar

Recently, a new link at the top of the screen has appeared on all web applications of a SharePoint 2013 enterprise farm on August 2018 CU. It has appeared in the main web app, mysites and central administration for all users. The link which should be there is "Reorganize or delete items in your Links list."

There is no custom control in that bar and it isn't part of the HTML suite bar. It looks like a deprecated feature from 2007 which is resurfaced.

Anyone have any ideas how I can remove this except for using CSS?

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Collection Feature and Site Feature in site settings, and check if a feature about this.

And using Chrome or IE F12 to find the HTML of the link "Reorganize or delete items in your Links list." and write the CSS to hide it, then add the CSS code into the master page.

Example the link HTML like below,

```
<a title="Manage Links" href="/">Reorganize or delete items in your Links list.</a>
```

and we can use the following CSS style to hide it.

```
<style>
a[title='Manage Links']{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I can see there isn't a feature for this I am aware of CSS, however, I want to fix the root of it, not just mask it.